# ASP .NET Core Identity is not working as supposed in ASP .NET Core 5.0 Razor Pages Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I'm a very new to ASP .NET Core Identity.

I have ASP .NET Core 5.0 Razor Pages Web Application where I have:

Class for **User** that extends **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser**:

```
public partial class User: IdentityUser<Int64>
{
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int64 RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Class for **UserRole** that extends **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole**:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityRole<Int64>
{
    [Required]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext extends **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext**:

```
public partial class MyDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User, UserRole, Int64>
{
    public virtual DbSet<Some_other_class_in_MyDbContext> Some_other_class { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
         
         ....
         
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //To get rid of an error - "The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<long>' requires a primary key to be defined"
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        ....
        
    }
}
```

I've scaffolded default Identity pages (Register, Login, User data edit, etc.) and added some more pages for displaying some user-related diagrams. After that I simply use:

1. **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager** for Login, Logout and check whether user is logged-in (**PasswordSignInAsync()**, **SignOutAsync()** and **IsSignedIn()**)
2. **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager** to create user, assign user to role and get current user (**CreateAsync()**, **AddToRoleAsync()** and **GetUserId\GetUserAsync()**)

Most of that functions use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ClaimsPrincipal User` (the comment for this field is - ***Gets the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal of the current logged in user***). And I suppose user identification to work just out-of-the-box.

But while performing some concurrency tests for working with different users that are signed-in at the same time (several browsers on same PC or several PC's connection same web server) - I've faced a user identifying problem. If two users sign-in to different login accounts at almost same time they can both have same value in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ClaimsPrincipal User` variable (Identity system recognize them as same user). I definitely know that because each page in my application has User Name and Surname on the top of it. If second user (who has incorrect value in variable) after that refreshes the page he is currently on - he obtains correct value in variable. Very strange...

My application has over 40 different pages. I can't even imagine that I need to have some collection to persist each page's current state for each logged-in user. For me it's a huge overkill - as I said earlier, I expected Identity to just work out-of-the-box. There are several tables in my database (**AspNetRoleClaims**, **AspNetUserClaims**, **AspNetUserLogins**, **AspNetUserClaims**) that I've expected to hold all necessary data for this system to work.

Am I doing something the wrong way?

Comment: `If second user (who has incorrect value in variable) after that refreshes the page he is currently on - he obtains correct value in variable.` Do you mean that another user uses different login account to sign in your site, but your identity system recognize them as same user? And if possible, please share your detailed testing flow, so that we can understand and troubleshoot the problem better.

Comment: @FeiHan Exactly - second user uses different login account to sign. Testing flow was just a manual site testing on a server. Two person performed all that actions that real user supposed to do (login, view diagrams, logout, login, edit user data and so on) using different login accounts. Several time identity system recognized them as same user. I don't really know what info to provide maybe **Program.cs** or **Startup.cs**?

Comment: This can't be. You're probably making a mistake somewhere... And these user accounts are logged in from different browsers you say?